# C# and XAML pass button Click String to another page textblock

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to pass a String to a textblock in a different xaml page

I have a page (Gender.xaml) where there is two buttons (male and female,) when the user clicks the button it will open another page of questions.

I am trying to display the Gender of what button the user selects in a label TextBlock at the top of the question.xaml page.

Does any one what the code is to pass/display the string value in the other Questions.xaml page

Here's what I have so far in the Gender.xaml page

```
  private void MaleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Questions.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        GenderLabel.Text = string.Format("Male");

    }

  private void FemaleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Questions.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        GenderLabel.Text = string.Format("Female");

    }
```

any help or advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The working way is the following

```
string gender = "Male"; // or "Female";
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Questions.xaml?gender=" + gender, UriKind.Relative));
```

On Questions.xaml.cs you have:

```
override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string gender = e.Uri.OriginalString.Replace("/Questions.xaml?gender=","");
    //you do what you want with gender;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Navigate like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Questions),"female");
```

And on the navigated page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string gender = e.Parameter.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This refers to Windows 8 but in his example you can see the Navigate requires a Uri witch means it is Windows Phone